# php redirect with HTTP query string variables

Tags: php, redirect, query-string

atm I'm using the following four lines to redirect the user to another page on my website:

```
<?php
    header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: ./content/index.html");
    exit;
?>
```

but there is a problem with the use of HTTP query string variables like `http://< url >?param=blah`
they don't get appended to url understandably.

Is there a smart move for implementing this?

greetings

Comment: I believe that you should use a fully qualifiedly uri so try `http://domain.tld/path?get=params` instead of `/path?get=params`, otherwise you may have to create a landing page with the meta redirect element.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? There are several possible interpretations

Comment: I#m sorry this was a http://domain.tld/path?get=params

Comment: but i wrote "< domain >" system changed it automatically;)

Comment: I found I had to remove all of the indent spacing before `header(...` before it would work https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php but it did work with a string of queries assembled from all of the  `htmlspecialchars($_GET['foo']...htmlspecialchars($_GET['moo'] ` etc and assembling the search queries  into a single var `$bar` with ` . '&' . ` in between each of them so then `header("Location: $bar ");` works without `htmlspecialchars() ` messing up the `&`

Answer (score 105, accepted):

```
<?php
    header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location:./content/index.html?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: Is it safe? Do we need to encode the query string in any way?

Comment: To avoid the risk of XSS attacks it would be wise to sanitise $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] with htmlspecialchars()

Comment: @nfrost21, this unfortunately won't work if you have more than one param, as htmlspecialchars() encodes the & delimiter and breaks the params.

Comment: This code will add an extra ? if no query string is passed

Comment: as @jontro pointed out, you better use something like:
 header("Location:./content/index.html" . ($_GET ? "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : "")); To avoid adding an extra ? if there is no query string.

Comment: @nfrost21 how does a redirect with query params increase the risk of XSS attacks? You are just redirecting with the query params that your user already sent to you, so i theese params can cause XSS they would've caused it event in the original page. Risk of XSS comes if you use your params badly (eg. you echo them unescaped in the page (Reflect XSS))

Answer (score 18):

To do the redirect and make sure an extra question mark does not show up when query string is not passed use the following

```
function preserve_qs() {
    if (empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "?") === false) {
        return "";
    }
    return "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ./content/index.html" . preserve_qs());
```

Answer (score 10):

I would like to add one more option...

Anyways - like others have said, using (*.htaccess*) *mod_rewrite* would probably be the best option.

**However,
 there surely can be many situations when you have to do it in PHP => you have 2 options:**

1. Append your redirection URI with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`
2. **Append your redirection URI with a *query built on your own* : `http_build_query($_GET);`**

**Option 2. - Advantages (+)**

- Encodes the parameters ( default by *PHP_QUERY_RFC1738* )
- you can easily add (or remove) some `$_GET` params like:
  `$_GET['new_param']="new value";` (add)
  `unset($_GET['param_to_remove']);` (remove)
- if environment (god knows why) does not provide a *QUERY_STRING* - you are probably still able to get the superglobal `$_GET` => environmentaly independent
- `http_build_query()`'s 1st param can actually be ANY array or object so you can build a `$_GET`-like request from `$_POST` or `$o = new YourObject();` if necessary
- you can change  argument separator if necessary

**Option 2. - Dissadvantages (-)**

- this kind of building query might be redundant ("good-for-nothing"), just unnecessary...
- if the query is big enaugh (maybe some attack?) it could have an affect on performace, because everytime there will be an array converted to a string & encoded

For more info see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php - a PHP manual's site about the `http_build_query()` function which `Returns a URL-encoded string.`

Answer (score 4):

Using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and appending it to the end of your redirect might be what you're looking for.

**EDIT:** Just noticed I was a bit late with my reply.

Answer (score 2):

First off why not redirect with mod rewrite?

But anyways, you can concat $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to the end of your url

Comment: I am finding mod_rewrite is really difficult to redirect query strings unless you know what they are going to be in advance. Either that or results in google search overcomplicate things.

Comment: @decker I think the google results you found are overcomplicating things. In principle it's no different than the accepted answer. Except with mod_rewrite instead of php.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or `QUERY_STRING`. Do a `print_r($_SERVER);` to see more information about the requested URL.

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for this task, you can be more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for providing a link to the documentation!