# how to rewrite url while use post method

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I use post method to login the user, and after the user successfully login, they will be redirect to `index.php`. The problem is that every user gets the same home page url, instead, I want to have somthing like `index.php/u=daniel` so every one can have their own unique url

Comment: why a per-user url? Can't you just store their username in the session and go from there?

Comment: You log in the user. I assume this login session is known. Why don't you access some `$_SESSION` variable in index.php to tell if the user is logged in, and if this is the case alter the page? Even if that username was available during the login process, it doesn't make sense to have it as a get variable in your url.

Comment: How about a header redirect after the login?

Comment: i do store their user name into a session, and in the login.php(which validate the authentic user, if password and username match, they will be directed to home page, with location('header: index.php')), but i want something like index.php?u=username

Comment: probably, something like index.php/username is what i want, i didn't mean a get variable in my url

Comment: So, if someone doesn't log in and go to index.php/username you want them to see index.php as that user?! Then why do you let them log in in the first place?

Comment: no, the only purpose for me to write something like index.php/username, is just for displaying purposes, I have a redirect function in index.php, if the user is not logging in, he or she will be redirected to a login page

Answer (score 0):

The instruction for doing what you want can be found here:
[php redirect with HTTP query string variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702149/php-redirect-with-http-query-string-variables)

However, I doubt it will be useful to have the username in the url. Like Marc said, you should just store the username in the session.

Comment: I do store the username in the session, now, I have my url like profile.php for every user profile page, which makes no sense, and what I want is just to figure out a way to rewrite the url and change it into somthing like profile.php/u=username