# How to redirect with parameters

Tags: wordpress

I have the code in functions.php which redirects user to specific page if they are visiting the first time and are on homepage (with use of the cookie).

**Question**: How can I add parameters to the url that I'm redirecting user to - with parameters that they've come to the homepage?

**Example**:

1. User comes to **www.mypage.com/index.php** with parameter
   **?user=someone**
2. Then the redirect happens to **www.mypage.com/somepage**
3. I want to add to the redirect url the parameter **?user=someone**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you show us some code of what have you already tried so we can better help you? Also, what language are you using? (PHP?)

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702149/php-redirect-with-http-query-string-variables

Answer (score 0):

@johndoetheone,
did you mean?

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.mypage.com/somepage?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
?>
```

or

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.mypage.com/somepage?<?=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];?>">
```