# PHP - Redirect to another page after getting node values from current page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, dom

I want to redirect user to another page after getting node values from current page and passing them into the URL's parameter, here is my code:

```
<?php

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $html = file_get_contents(home_url(). $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    $addresses =   $dom->getElementsByTagName('address');


    foreach ($addresses as $key => $address) {
            $add[$key] = $address->nodeValue;
    }


   $fields['address'] = urlencode($add[0]);

    $qry = http_build_query($fields);

    if(!empty($qry)){  
        header( 'Location: http://example.com/subscription-form/?' . $qry) ;  
       }

       ?>
```

It does redirect successfully, but `http_build_query` values are empty. Here's an example of redirect: `http://example.com/subscription-form/?address=` , the URL is without the value of `$_GET['address']` .

Comment: Maybe `$add[0]` isn't set. Try a little debug with `var_dump($add); die();` after the `foreach` loop

Comment: @d79 $add[0] is set and there are a few more variables which I haven't included in this code to avoid lengthy code; are also set.

Comment: Try adding `exit;` after the redirection ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702149/php-redirect-with-http-query-string-variables#4702187))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP redirect didn't work, so I tried it with JavaScript and it worked:

```
    $redir = '<script type="text/javascript">';
    $redir.= 'window.location.href="http://example.com/subscription-form/?';
    $redir.= $qry .'"';
    $redir.= '</script>';

    echo $redir;
```

and yes, there's no need to `urlencode` as it's already done by `http_build_query`.