# PHP callback URL is not including ?a=complete

Tags: php

I am trying to change the call back URL from one URL to another. Current callback URL is

```
header("Location: ".$gatewayParams['systemurl']."/viewinvoice.php?id=" . $merchant_order_id);
```

I wanted to change the URL to `https://example.com/cart.php?a=complete`
When I tried replacing `/viewinvoice.php?id=` with `/cart.php?a=complete` I am getting redirected to `https://example.com/cart.php`, and the `?a=complete` gets stripped.

Can someone tell me the way to reach https://example.com/cart.php?a=complete

Please Note: 
1.  I am not a PHP developer, so if you are suggesting something, kindly provide a full code snippet. 
2. My goal is to redirect the user to the 'https://example.com/cart.php?a=complete'. It is Okay to make it hardcoded if it needs programmatic logic.
3. Please find the actual use case [here](https://whmcs.community/topic/291489-via-shareasale-affiliate-link-after-payment-redirecting-to-viewinvoicephp-instead-of-cartphpacomplete/)

I found that if I can get this callback URL fixed, then it will solve my problem

Comment: just store it into a `$_GET['variable']` variable before calling the header function and access it on `viewinvoice.php`

Comment: Note that some browsers like to hide those parameters from the url until you click the address bar. Maybe that is what's happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php redirect with HTTP query string variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702149/php-redirect-with-http-query-string-variables)

Comment: No @DirkScholten it is just an issue with the call back URL based on some criteria. I will edit the question to provide much more insight.

Comment: Do you **really** try to redirect to **example.com** or are you using your own domain? It's possible that the redirect works from PHP, but the query is "stripped" by the website settings.

Comment: Yes, @AlexShesterov I am trying my domain. Please find the actual use case [here] (https://whmcs.community/topic/291489-via-shareasale-affiliate-link-after-payment-redirecting-to-viewinvoicephp-instead-of-cartphpacomplete/)

So, as I mentioned, if I can get to the full URL including `?a=complete` will solve my issue.

Comment: So your domain is `mydomain.com`, as mentioned in the linked thread. Is this correct?

Comment: No @AlexShesterov, my domain is https://hostmywebsite.online/. I thought that in a forum like this it is not a good idea to post the actual domain.

You know some moderators may get it removed, though I am unsure about Stackoverflow

Comment: Hi @kenzotenma, could you please share the full code, so I can try and reply here?

Comment: Your PHP code for writing `Location` header is all good. The website itself redirects from `https://hostmywebsite.online/cart.php?a=complete` to `/cart.php` via `HTTP 302`: `HTTP/2.0 302 Found ... location: /cart.php`. So the problem is in the web server settings.

Comment: Hello all,

Thank you so much for your input. My developer fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following

```
$callback_url = $gatewayParams['systemurl']."/viewinvoice.php?id=" . $merchant_order_id;
$callback_url = str_replace('/viewinvoice.php?id=', '/cart.php?a=complete', $callback_url);
header("Location: ".$callback_url);
```

Comment: Hi @AliRazaGhori, the same thing happening here. 
`?a=complete` is not added to the URL

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly are you trying to do. Anyhow, if I were to redirect via header function to a URL with some extra params. I'd put it into a GET variable. So, if an http request comes to `example.php`

```
// example.php
<?php
$merchant_id = 123;
$_GET['merchant_id'] = $merchant_id;
header('Location: invoice.php');
```

And, in invoice.php

```
// invoice.php
if( isset($_GET['merchant_id']) ) {
  $merchant_id = $_GET['merchant_id'];
  unset($_GET['merchant_id']);
}
```