# Stuck trying to redirect urls in PHP

Tags: php

I've searched around and struggled to come up with a solution to this.

I've inherited a project with several thousand php files, each of which has multiple links in the form of:

```
<a href="_link.php?[RANDOMSTRING]">
```

Trouble is, I don't have the _link.php file.

I'm assuming its some kind of redirect script, as it is supposed to send the user to

```
RANDOMSTRING.php
```

when clicked.

It doesn't do anything nice like use a variable name like

```
_link.php?url=[RANDOMSTRING]
```

What code do I need to put into _link.php to just get it working for now. Its a hacky job and I'm planing a major overall and sticking all of this content into a database, but for now I just need the flatfile version running.

Cheers for your help.

Comment: The random string is probably there to break browser cache.

Comment: If you don't know what this file was meant to do, and it doesn't exist, I'm not sure why you think we'd know what code you'd need :P

Comment: What about this answer from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4702187/1291935 seems like you should be able to use it to remake your _link.php file

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there are not actual `[]`, then a hack is to create the file `_link.php` and inside, either redirect:

```
<?php
header("location: {$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}.php");
exit;
```

Or possibly include if that would work:

```
<?php
include("{$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}.php");
```

If there are actual `[]` then just trim them:

```
trim($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '[]');
```